# ICLRRuntimeHost Start method never returns

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr

I'm injecting an unmanaged DLL into another unmanaged process. The goal here is to use this bootstrapper to initialize the CLR so I can use the .NET framework in the target process. Injecting works fine, however attempting to start the CLR and load my managed library is causing me issues. Here's my code I'm attempting to start the CLR with (called right from DLLMain):

```
void Init() {
    ICLRRuntimeHost *pClrHost = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CorBindToRuntimeEx(NULL, L"wks", 0, CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (PVOID*)&pClrHost);

    MessageBox(NULL, L"attempt start", L"Dll", MB_OK);
    hr = pClrHost->Start();
    MessageBox(NULL, L"past start", L"Dll", MB_OK);

    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    hr = pClrHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"C:\\Users\\Blank\\Documents\\ManagedLibrary.dll", L"Namespace.Class", L"Main", L"Parameters", &dwRet);
}
```

My first message box pops up fine but calling Start() seems to block and never return. This then results in the target process becoming unresponsive. Commenting out Start() and attempting to immediately execute has an identical result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm attempting to start the CLR with (called right from DLLMain)

You cannot start the CLR from inside `DllMain`. `DllMain` is a very hostile place where you basically cannot do a lot of things, without getting problems due to the fact that the (global) loader lock is held while code runs within `DllMain`. In your example, most likely, `ICLRRuntimeHost.Start()` tries to do something that would also want to lock this loader lock and thus blocks (deadlocks). You should be able to see that with a debugger.

Raymond Chen (oldnewthing) has written a couple of blog posts about this and related issues, for example [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873) one.

Comment: How would I go about starting the CLR then, if I cannot do it inside of DLLMain? I'm injecting into a completely separate process so I cannot use PInvoke to call some other method.

Comment: I believe there are other questions related on SO. I'm no expert here, but you could try to inject a remote thread (`CreateRemoteThread`) and launch it from there.